# Reading the day for the current month SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

This is my current query that works, but I still need days to print out for the whole month starting 2018-05-01, not to skip, is this possible in a sql?

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) , 
    @MaxDate DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1);

SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @MinDate, @MaxDate) + 1)
Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @MinDate) INTO     #MYCALENDAR FROM sys.all_objects a CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b;

SELECT  
a.LPE_Pensum,  
DATEPART(DAY, CAL.[Date]) AS Tag ,
LEFT(datename(WEEKDAY, CAL.[Date] ),3) AS Datum,
CAL.[Date],
p.ZPZ_Von, 
p.ZPZ_Bis FROM
#MYCALENDAR CAL 
LEFT JOIN Z_PRAESENZZEIT AS p ON CONVERT(DATE, p.ZPZ_Datum) = CONVERT(DATE, CAL.[Date])
LEFT JOIN A_PERSONAL AS a ON a.LPE_ID = p.ZPZ_LPE_ID 
LEFT JOIN A_Arbeitszeitplan AS r on r.LPE_AbteilungID = a.LPE_AbteilungID 
LEFT JOIN A_Abteilung AS b ON b.LPE_AbteilungID = r.LPE_AbteilungID WHERE a.LPE_ID=13
```

and this is the result of a query:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQOCw.png)

Thanks for your help

Comment: For future reference, a bit of question asking etiquette - 1.) Don't link to images. The reason for this is two fold: you can't copy/paste the data from an image and most people taking a cyberloaf break on SO at work aren't going to just follow some link. Post well formatted copy/pastable text with sample data and expected results. 2.) Tag your DBMS (SQL Server I assume).

Comment: @Error_2646 that you are right, I apologize, I am new

Comment: @GrantWinney I do not know him, but I think he's well-corrected

Comment: @neven No worries, it's for mutual benefit. Well formed questions are more likely to get quick, quality answers.

Comment: @Error_2646 That's right, thank you

Comment: As others have said, a calendar table or date dimension will make your issue easy to resolve. Probably my favorite go-to to get started building out a calendar table is Aaron Bertrand's link: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/ It's been around for a few years, but still full of some good knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to scan a particular range of dates, lets say previous month:

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) , -1st day prev month
        @MaxDate DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1); -- last day prev month
```

Now what you need is a calendar table to store your dates:

```
SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @MinDate, @MaxDate) + 1)
        Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @MinDate)
INTO    #MYCALENDAR
FROM    sys.all_objects a
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b;
```

We can use our new `#MYCALENDAR` as baseline for our query:

```
SELECT  
    a.LPE_Pensum,  
    DATEPART(DAY, CAL.[Date]) AS Tag ,
    LEFT(datename(WEEKDAY, CAL.[Date] ),3) AS Datum,
    CAL.[Date],
    p.ZPZ_Von, 
    p.ZPZ_Bis 
FROM
    #MYCALENDAR CAL 
    LEFT JOIN Z_PRAESENZZEIT AS p ON CONVERT(DATE, p.ZPZ_Datum) = CONVERT(DATE, CAL.[Date])
    LEFT JOIN A_PERSONAL AS a ON a.LPE_ID = p.ZPZ_LPE_ID 
    LEFT JOIN A_Arbeitszeitplan AS r on r.LPE_AbteilungID = a.LPE_AbteilungID 
    LEFT JOIN A_Abteilung AS b ON b.LPE_AbteilungID = r.LPE_AbteilungID 
WHERE 
    a.LPE_ID=13
```

you may have to change something in your join clauses but, basically, this is how i would proceed.

Comment: Thanks for your post, but I do not know how to replace this part * "- edit with real A_PERSONAL Date field"*, in that table I do not have a date, my date is in Z_PRAESENZZEIT tables

Comment: That's great, all dates have been printed for this month, and what do I have to add to the show and the days in that month for which the worker was not present?

Comment: the `NULL` values in p.ZPZ_Von means they were no present

Comment: Yes, but, this is my result, Date: 1,3,5,15 ... and I need every day in the month to be displayed as days, and ZPZ_Von and ZPZ_Bis to be set to NULL if there is no data for that day

Comment: please edit your main post and show your current output and an example of desired output...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try to indent your query, it's impossible to read it that way. Second, you can create a dates table with all the days you are interested in. Search in internet for date dimensions, they will fit very well with your need. And finally, you must left join your query with this table, in order to have a way to see all the days not present in your data.
It would be something like this:

```
SELECT 
  a.LPE_Pensum,  
  dd.[DAY] AS Tag ,
  LEFT(datename(WEEKDAY, p.ZPZ_Datum ),3) AS Datum,  
  p.ZPZ_Datum,p.ZPZ_Von, 
  p.ZPZ_Bis 
FROM [DATE_DIM] dd
  LEFT JOIN Z_PRAESENZZEIT AS p 
    ON dd.[DATE]=DATEPART(DAY, p.ZPZ_Datum)
  LEFT JOIN A_PERSONAL AS a 
    ON a.LPE_ID = p.ZPZ_LPE_ID
   AND a.LPE_ID=13
  LEFT JOIN A_Arbeitszeitplan AS r 
    on r.LPE_AbteilungID = a.LPE_AbteilungID 
  LEFT JOIN A_Abteilung AS b 
    ON b.LPE_AbteilungID = r.LPE_AbteilungID 
WHERE dd.[YEAR]=@YearInterestedIn
```

The dd.[YEAR]=@YearInterestedIn must be replaced by the range you are interested in your study

Comment: This format isn't much better than the original as far as readability goes. It is a wall of text query.

Comment: You haven't seen the original (in one line), it has changed

Comment: I can see the history and yes it was bad, but telling somebody they should format their query to make it easier read and then this....

Comment: What's your problem? Are you bored? For me this query is easy to read, not all the queries are a select * from table. Take a coffee

Comment: @JaimeDrq thank you for reporting, but I do not think this is an adequate answer that can help me

Comment: @neven, no problem. You can wait someone create that table for you and for sure it will be easier, but believe me it's the way to do it.

Comment: Yes using either a date or a tally table is the best approach here.

Comment: @JaimeDrq yeah, here I am trying to do this this way

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate the days for the current month.  Assuming you have *some rows* in your database, then you can use `left join` to bring in the dates:

```
SELECT a.LPE_Pensum, d.dte AS Tag ,
       LEFT(datename(WEEKDAY, d.dte),3) AS Datum,
       p.ZPZ_Datum, p.ZPZ_Von,  p.ZPZ_Bis 
FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT CAST(p.ZPZ_Datum as date) as dte
       FROM Z_PRAESENZZEIT p
       WHERE ZPZ_Datum >= datefromparts(year(p.ZPZ_Datum), month(p.ZPZ_Datum), 1) AND
             ZPZ_Datum >= dateadd(month, 1, datefromparts(year(p.ZPZ_Datum), month(p.ZPZ_Datum), 1))
    ) d LEFT JOIN
    (A_PERSONAL a JOIN
     Z_PRAESENZZEIT p
     ON a.LPE_ID = p.ZPZ_LPE_ID 
    ) 
    ON p.ZPZ_Datum >= d.dte AND p.ZPZ_Datum < DATEADD(day, 1, d.dte) LEFT JOIN
    A_Arbeitszeitplan r
    ON r.LPE_AbteilungID = a.LPE_AbteilungID 
    A_Abteilung b
    ON b.LPE_AbteilungID = r.LPE_AbteilungID 
WHERE a.LPE_ID = 13;
```

You can generate the dates in a different fashion if necessary.

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linof, thanks for the post, with your code I get this bug, how can I fix it?"DATEFROMPARTS is not recognized as the name of a built-in function."

Comment: @neven . . . It is a very valid SQL Server function and has been supported for many years:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017.

Comment: Linof ok, but I have two faults in your case because it is ON ON twice and the other error occurs in the part of "A_Abteilung b" which should I correct?